# Debian Buster: install yarnpkg as yarn

Tags: debian, javascript

I have installed yarn - Node.js package manager (alternative to npm):

```
$ sudo apt install yarnpkg
...
$ dpkg -l | grep yarn
ii  yarnpkg                           1.13.0-1                     all          Fast, reliable and secure npm alternative
```

But it has installed only the `yarnpkg` command:

```
$ dpkg -L yarnpkg | grep usr/bin/
/usr/bin/yarnpkg
```

I think this is some Debian-specific change? I have expected that the command would be `yarn` like elsewhere (for example when installed from [official yarn repository](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#debian-stable)).

Why is it this way? How can I make it possible to run `yarnpkg` as `yarn`? Is there any standardized way, did I miss something, or should I just create symlink `/usr/local/bin/yarn`?

Comment: The symlink worked for me, but I am also still curious, why is it this way on debian. I tried to `apt search yarn` and didn't find a conflicting package name.

Answer (score 10):

Just create a symlink

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/yarnpkg /usr/bin/yarn`

Why a symlink?

unlike an alias the symlink will work for all users and in every shell.
Also scripts usually either assume to have the `yarn` command in current path or do something like `which yarn` to find the executable. Both is solved by the symlink

Comment: I was about to create an alias but wanted to check alternatives (and explanations). Found this :)

Comment: This is a great answer. (A hardlink would also work.)
The reason they changed the name is because there is an older app also named yarn.

Comment: You shouldn't manually create files in `/usr/bin`, use `/usr/local/bin` instead: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarn` (of course `/usr/local/bin` should be in your `PATH` as well)

Answer (score 3):

In ~/.bashrc put the line:

```
alias yarn="yarnpkg"
```

Comment: I think this is not always enough, because some Javascript files executed during install, build etc. are executing "yarn" directly, not via shell.

Comment: Not enough indeed

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have installed it in Debian 10:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
apt update
apt install yarn
```

Works as it should. Basically ditch the yarn from debian repo and instead use official yarn directly